# How to validate a pattern in lua

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, validation

I'm currently creating a search function in lua which basically just goes through a list of items and processes the items that match the input string in a specific way.
I use `string.find(sourceString, inputString)` to identify the items.

The function is called whenever a user types something into a text field so if he tries to enter a pattern it happens that when using sets or captures the function is called when the search string just contains a `[` or `a` ( without the closing equivalent which of cause throws an error.

The best way to go around this problem I think is to validate the input as beeing a valid pattern, but I've got no idea how to do this. Lua itself doesn't seem to contain a method for this and I am a bit confused of how to check it in a more or less performant way myself. Thanks for your help and ideas in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap the call to `string.find` with `pcall` to capture the error.

```
local status, result = pcall(string.find, sourceString, inputString)
if not status then
    -- bad pattern logic, error message is in result
else
    -- good pattern logic, result contains the start index
end
```

Comment: If you want special characters to be "active" in pattern, then yes, it is, probably, the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Looks nice, the only problem I'd see is that I would get to the validity check when I'm actually trying to already apply the pattern. I think from a coding point it would be nice to validate the string before the first application. Nevertheless, I think I'll do exactly this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://github.com/lua-nucleo/lua-nucleo/blob/master/lua-nucleo/string.lua#L137-158) for pattern escape function (taken from somewhere in [Lua Users](http://lua-users.org/wiki) wiki, I think). You may convert it to the validation function if you need.

Comment: `s1 = string.gsub(s1, "(%W)", "%%%1")` from http://www.lua.org/pil/20.4.html seems more concise. But, if that is all that is wanted then why not just use the plain parameter to `string.find`. I think that the question is how to deal with bad patterns, not how to escape a string.

Comment: @gwell: it is not immediately clear from the question, if OP wants to allow special characters at all.

Comment: @gwell: concise: yes, but it can lead to much longer strings, so it is not necessarily better.

Comment: I actually generally want to allow the pattern matching. To disable those I could also set the optional third parameter of find to "true" so the input sequence would be treated as plain text. But this might give me a starting point for a validation function nevertheless. I might be able to count the paranthesis and look for matching counts. I'll try that out if the other solution (seems easier to implement) works :) Thanks!